# How to receive and send in different threads with C sockets

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets

I am trying to send and receive in different threads. When I use the code below I get a bad address error, I guess because my server address could not be properly passed to the thread function.

Code:

```
#include "client.h"

struct global_table{
  struct sockaddr_in *serveraddr;
  int sockID;
};

void *recvFromServer(struct global_table *rec){
  char recBuf[RECVBUFSIZE];
  int serverSize = sizeof(rec->serveraddr);

  while(1)
  {
    int n = recvfrom(rec->sockID, recBuf, RECVBUFSIZE, 0, &rec->serveraddr, &serverSize);
    if (n < 0)
      perror("ERROR in recvfrom");
    decryptData(recBuf);
    printf("Recieved: %s\n", recBuf);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
  }
}

void pingServer(char *hostname, int portno)
{
  int sockfd, n, serverlen;
  struct sockaddr_in serveraddr;
  struct sockaddr_in client_addr; 
  struct hostent *server;
  char *buf;

  sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
  if (sockfd < 0) 
    perror("ERROR opening socket");

  server = gethostbyname(hostname);
  if (server == NULL) 
    perror("ERROR, no host found");

  bzero((char *) &serveraddr, sizeof(serveraddr));
  serveraddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  bcopy((char *)server->h_addr, (char *)&serveraddr.sin_addr.s_addr, server->h_length);
  serveraddr.sin_port = htons(portno);

  client_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  client_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
  client_addr.sin_port = htons(5500);

  if (bind(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)&client_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr)) == -1)
    perror("Socket could not be binded");

  if(setsockopt(sockfd,IPPROTO_IP,IP_TOS,&tos,sizeof(tos)))
    perror("Could not set socket option");

  pthread_t threads[2];
  serverlen = sizeof(serveraddr);
  struct global_table server_info;

  server_info.sockID = sockfd;
  server_info.serveraddr = &serveraddr;

  pthread_create(&threads[0],NULL,recvFromServer, &server_info); // Trying to recv on a different thread
  pthread_join(threads[0],NULL);

}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  char *hostname;
  int portno;
  if (argc != 3)
    perror("usage: <hostname> <port>\n");

  hostname = argv[1];
  portno = atoi(argv[2]);
  pingServer(hostname, portno);
  return 0;
}
```

How can I fix the problem?

Comment: It works on the main thread. I think the way it should be passed to struct and then get the address is problematic.

Comment: looks like too much indirection on that recvfrom call, is the compiler complaining. `&rec->serveraddr` shoudl surely be `rec->serveraddr`

Comment: If i run everything on the main thread, the code works fine. No errors on compile time.

Comment: `struct global_table` contains a pointer to `struct sockaddr_in`, and you take the address of that pointer to pass to `recvfrom()` -- that's one too many levels of indirection.  Also, you point the `serveraddr` member at a struct that's local to the `pingServer()` function, then try to use it after that function returns (via the thread you created right before returning)... the struct isn't valid anymore then, and you'd have undefined behaviour even if the indirection were correct.

Comment: Your `recvFromServer()` is technically not of the correct type for a thread-start function.  Its argument must be of type `void *`, not `struct global_table *`.  If the argument is a value of the latter type converted to the former type, then the function can safely cast it back after receiving it.  Your compiler should be warning you about this, though in practice it will work on many implementations.

Comment: @Dmitri, can you please state how should i correct it ?, should i allocate the memory in the function for the struct address and then point the global table to it ? and then use it in the recvFromServer method ?

Comment: Both the `struct global_table` and the `struct sockaddr_in` you point to from it need to persist for the duration of the thread... they could be dynamically allocated, made global, made static, etc.  Maybe dynamically allocate them before creating the thread and then free them at the end of the thread function.

Comment: `server_info` lives on `pingServer()`'s stack which is invalid a wink after the `pthread_create()` returned. Also the whole process, along with all it's threads ends another wink later, the moment `main()` `return`s. To fix this you could for example add a call to `pthread_join()` after having created the thread.

Comment: @alk, can you point me to any example which uses UDP sockets to rec and send on different threads at the same time. The behaviour i need to achieve is that send function will send a lines read from a file, meanwhile recFromServer function can recieve anything send from the server. The error comes as "socket operation on non socket" once my main thread finishes and waits for the second thread by using pthread_join(tid, NULL). Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the problems noted in the comments (and by now, this problem is also noted in the comments...), this line

```
struct global_table server_info;
```

creates a local variable in your `pingServer()` function.

This line

```
pthread_create(&threads[0],NULL,recvFromServer, &server_info); // Trying to recv on a different thread
```

of code passes the address of that variable to the `recvFromServer()` function, which will run in a different thread.  But then `pingServer()` immediately returns and the local `server_info` variable ceases to exist.

One fix is to define the `server_info` and `serveraddr` variable as `static`:

```
static struct global_table server_info;
static struct sockaddr_in serveraddr;
```

That will create *one* copy of the `server_info` variable that will be shared by every invocation of `pingServer()`, but that one copy will exist for the lifetime of your program.

Comment: I get your point but still this does not resolve the issue. The error it says at run time is "ERROR in recvfrom: Bad address".

Comment: It's not just `struct global_table server_info`, but also `struct sockaddr_in serveraddr` which `server_info.serveraddr` gets pointed at that would need to be static.  And, that would still mean he couldn't later call `pingServer()` more than once to have more than one thread at a time.

Comment: @Dmitri Absolutely true.